# After successful login, I get redirected to login page again ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have login page in which login control is used, everything works fine in local machine but not working on server. after successfull login without any bug or error it again redirecting to login page.
below is my code. 
web.config

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin,user"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="RJD" domain="abc.net" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Admin/ApproveComments.aspx" timeout="60" path="/">
      </forms>
    </authentication>

 protected void ctrLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
            clsAuthenticate objauthonticate = new clsAuthenticate();

            try
            {
                objauthonticate.user = ctrLogin.UserName.Trim();
                objauthonticate.Pasword = ctrLogin.Password.Trim();
                if (objauthonticate.Authonticate())
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = objauthonticate.user.ToString();
                    CreateTicket();
                    e.Authenticated = true;
                //    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(ctrLogin.UserName, ctrLogin.RememberMeSet);
                    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/ApproveComments.aspx");

                }
                else
                {
                    e.Authenticated = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw ex;
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
            }

        }
        private void CreateTicket()
        {


            clsAuthenticate oblogin = new clsAuthenticate();
            string role = oblogin.getRoleByID(Session["user"].ToString());

            FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(ctrLogin.Password, "sha1");

            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "Forms", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, role);

            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
```

Comment: What's the Authentication type set in your IIS? Should enable Forms Authentication.

Comment: @Sam: 

Allow Anonymous Access,
Integrated Windows Authentication and
Basic Authentication

Comment: You should have forms authentication enabled. If the windows feature is not installed (if you can't see the option in IIS) you must do that.

Comment: Dont have server access, any alternate option.

Comment: You'll have to ask the server admin to do it. There's no alternate option if forms authentication is not there in IIS

Answer (score 0):

When a user authenticates to a Web site by using Forms Authentication, the server creates a cookie. The value of the cookie is an encrypted forms authentication ticket. The cookie is passed to the server on each request to the application, and the FormsAuthenticationModule class decrypts the cookie value and determines if the user is valid or not. 
I think you have blow tag in your project web.config. remove it

```
...
<modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
....
```